# jqgrid only displaying the group column name

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

How can I merge the jqgrid header. I only want to show the group header name. So far I have done this, the problem is I only want to show the group column name.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
...
   colNames: ['Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Closed', 'Shipped via', 'Notes'],
   colModel: [
         {name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y'}, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'},
         {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 70 },
         {name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 75, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', align: 'right'},
         {name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 75, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', align: 'right'},
         {name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 75, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', align: 'right'},
         {name: 'closed', index: 'closed', width: 75, align: 'center', formatter: 'checkbox',
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: {value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes'}},
         {name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 100, align: 'center', formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue: 'Intime'}},
         {name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 70, sortable: false}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
 ...
});
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: false, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<em>Price</em>'},
    {startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'}
  ]
});
```

Comment: It's not full clear what you want. Do you want to hide `'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total'` and `'Closed', 'Shipped via'`? How the columns could be sorted or resized?

Comment: @oleg I dont want sorting

Comment: @Oleg My grid have eight columns but i want to merge headers to three columns

Answer (score 4):

If you want just **display headers over multiple columns** and the sorting of data in the merged column is not interesting for you like the resizing of columns, then you can solve the problem without the usage of `setGroupHeaders`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleGrouppingOfColunmHeaders.htm) displays the following results

[image]

It uses `cmTemplate: { resizable: false }` option to set `resizable: false` for all columns, it uses `sortable: false` in some columns and it uses the following code after the grid is created:

```js
var newWidth = $("#list_amount").width() + $("#list_tax").outerWidth(true) +
        $("#list_total").outerWidth(true);
$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "amount", "<em>Price</em>", "", {
    style: "width: " + newWidth + "px;",
    colspan: "3"
});
$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "tax", "", "", {style: "display: none"});
$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "total", "", "", {style: "display: none"});
newWidth = $("#list_closed").width() + $("#list_ship_via").outerWidth(true);
$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "closed", "Shiping", "", {
    style: "width: " + newWidth + "px;",
    colspan: "2"
});
$grid.jqGrid("setLabel", "ship_via", "", "", {style: "display: none"});
```

The above code can have minimal problems with the column to header alignment less as 1px, but the most problem can be solved in the way.

Comment: without colspan is perfect in my case